How to scale images proportionally
I insert images into Excel based on a file path and then save them into a different folder.
When they are saved into the folder they aren't scaled proportionately. The ideal size would be 600px x 600 px but it's important they are resized proportionately.
Is there a way to keep the code running when an image isn't found? Currently it stops, a pop up appears and I have to click ok.
Sub InsertAndSaveImages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim imgFolder As String
    Dim imgName As String
    Dim imgCounter As Integer
    Dim imgCell As Range
    Dim imgPath As String
    Dim imgShape As Shape
    
    ' Set the worksheet where the file paths are stored
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw data")  ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    
    ' Set the workbook (this workbook)
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Folder path to save images
    imgFolder = wb.Path & "\Images\"
    
    ' Create the images folder if it doesn't exist
    If Dir(imgFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir imgFolder
    End If
    
    ' Loop through column A to insert and save images
    imgCounter = 1
    For Each imgCell In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        ' Get image path from column A
        imgPath = imgCell.Value
        
        ' Check if image path exists
        If Dir(imgPath) <> "" Then
            ' Extract image name from path
            imgName = Mid(imgPath, InStrRev(imgPath, "\") + 1)
            
            ' Insert image into worksheet
            Set imgShape = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imgPath, _
                                                LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                                SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                                Left:=100, _
                                                Top:=100, _
                                                Width:=200, _
                                                Height:=200)
            
            ' Save image to folder
            Call SaveImageToFile(imgShape, imgFolder & imgName)
            
            ' Clean up
            imgShape.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "Image file not found: " & imgPath, vbExclamation
        End If
        
        imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
    Next imgCell
    
    MsgBox "Images inserted and saved successfully to folder: " & imgFolder, vbInformation
End Sub

Sub SaveImageToFile(imgShape As Shape, SavePath As String)
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    
    ' Copy image shape to clipboard
    imgShape.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    
    ' Paste image into chart object
    Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, imgShape.Width, imgShape.Height)
    chartObj.Activate
    ActiveChart.Paste
    
    ' Export chart object as image file
    ActiveChart.Export fileName:=SavePath, Filtername:="jpg"
    
    ' Delete chart object
    chartObj.Delete
End Sub


Have you tried ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

Where would I put this in the code? ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

Tried it after the code below but it didn't help.  Set imgShape = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imgPath, _
LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
Left:=100, _
Top:=100, _
Width:=600, _
Height:=600)
' Lock aspect ratio of the image shape
imgShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

If i change the code to  ' Insert picture into worksheet
Set imgShape = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imgPath, _
LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
Left:=100, _
Top:=100, _
Width:=-1, _
Height:=-1) it keep the ratio but is there a way to change it so its 600 px x 600px?


If using Width:=-1, Height:=-1 to insert an image, then it keeps its original dimension.
Add a sub ResizeImg to resize the image to 600x600. If the image isn't a square (hight isn't same as width), only one dimension is 600, the other is smaller than 600. eg. the dimension of image is 300x200, the final size would be 600x400 after resizing.

Microsoft documentation:

Shapes.AddPicture method (Excel)

Sub InsertAndSaveImages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim imgFolder As String
    Dim imgName As String
    Dim imgCounter As Integer
    Dim imgCell As Range
    Dim imgPath As String
    Dim imgShape As Shape
    ' Set the worksheet where the file paths are stored
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw data")  ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    ' Set the workbook (this workbook)
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Folder path to save images
    imgFolder = wb.Path & "\Images\"
    ' Create the images folder if it doesn't exist
    If Dir(imgFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir imgFolder
    End If
    ' Loop through column A to insert and save images
    imgCounter = 1
    For Each imgCell In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        ' Get image path from column A
        imgPath = imgCell.Value
        ' Check if image path exists
        If Dir(imgPath) <> "" Then
            ' Extract image name from path
            imgName = Mid(imgPath, InStrRev(imgPath, "\") + 1)
            ' Insert image into worksheet **
            Set imgShape = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imgPath, _
                                                LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                                SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                                Left:=100, _
                                                Top:=100, _
                                                Width:=-1, _
                                                Height:=-1)
            Call ResizeImg(imgShape, 600, 600)
            ' Save image to folder
            Call SaveImageToFile(imgShape, imgFolder & imgName)
            ' Clean up
            imgShape.Delete
        Else
            ' MsgBox "Image file not found: " & imgPath, vbExclamation
            ' Print out missing file in Immediate Window
            Debug.Print "Image file not found: " & imgPath
        End If
        imgCounter = imgCounter + 1
    Next imgCell
    MsgBox "Images inserted and saved successfully to folder: " & imgFolder, vbInformation
End Sub
Sub ResizeImg(imgShape As Shape, ByVal iH As Long, ByVal iW As Long)
    Dim ratioH As Double, ratioW As Double, ratioResize As Double
    If Not imgShape Is Nothing Then
        ratioW = iW / imgShape.Width
        ratioH = iH / imgShape.Height
        ratioResize = IIf(ratioW < ratioH, ratioW, ratioH)
        imgShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        imgShape.Height = imgShape.Height * ratioResize
    End If
End Sub
Sub SaveImageToFile(imgShape As Shape, SavePath As String)
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    ' Copy image shape to clipboard
    imgShape.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    ' Paste image into chart object
    Set chartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, imgShape.Width, imgShape.Height)
    chartObj.Activate
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ' Export chart object as image file
    ActiveChart.Export Filename:=SavePath, Filtername:="jpg"
    ' Delete chart object
    chartObj.Delete
End Sub


I got an error message Run time error 13: type mismatch for Set imgShape = ws.Pictures.Insert(imgPath) when I ran it.

I've updated the code.
